# Simple algebra equation, proof needed

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

If:
$$a, \space b, \space c \in R$$
$$a(b,b^{2}) = (ab, (ab)^2)\space; \space \space (a, a^{2}) + (b, b^{2}) = (a + b, (a+b)^{2}) $$

how can I show that:
$$a[(b,b^{2}) + (c,c^{2})] = a(b,b^2) + a(c, c^{2})$$

??

Comment: This question desperately needs more context. You've tagged this linear-algebra; are you defining non-standard addition and scalar multiplication on a set? If so, what is the set, what is the $+$ operation, and what is the scalar field?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: The step in question looks completely wrong... unless the summation on $\Bbb{R}$ has also been redefined. Are you sure that this working is supposed to be valid? Is it a spot-the-mistake kind of exercise?

Comment: Nop, that was my train of thought but I guess its wrong... So I edited to match the books question

Comment: @user771918 the way it is presented now is the original question. Sorry for misleading you

Comment: It's fine. :) It's a bit of a shame that you got rid of your working. Ideally, on this site we like the question to be clear *and* to see your working.

Comment: well, true that and I have been doing it that way... But it was such a gross mistake that I felt embarrassed

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to embarrass you. :)

Comment: No problem, it was my fault!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $a[(b,b^2) + (c,c^2)] = a[(b+c,(b+c)^2)] = (a(b+c),a^2(b+c)^2)$. On the other hand, $a(b,b^2) + a(c,c^2) = (ab,a^2b^2) + (ac,a^2c^2) = (ab+ac,(ab+ac)^2) = (a(b+c), a^2(b+c)^2)$. Thus they are equal.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!